# How to do: for looping + increasing of radius each loop?

Tags: loops, for-loop, processing, radius

How do I create a clean and simple code that creates a circle of point/dots within the larger one? Or something similar (I can't post an image of what I want sorry). I was told to try using a for loop around the outside of my code and have the radius increase slightly each iteration of the loop. However, i don't know how to increase the radius?

This is the code I've been experimenting with so far:

```
size (400, 400);
background(255);
noStroke();
fill(0);
smooth();
translate(width/2, height/2);

int numpoints = 10;
float angleinc = 2 * PI / numpoints;
int radius = 100;

for (int i = 0; i < numpoints; i++) {
  float x = cos(angleinc * i) * radius;
  float y = sin(angleinc * i) * radius;

  ellipse(x, y, 4, 4);
}
```

Please, any quick help would be appreciated. Also, I'm fairly new to processing and coding, so I'm not the best...

Comment: What is the increase in radius expected. cant you just add radius = radius*x for where x is the increase in the for loop

Comment: Why can't you post an image of what you want? Just mock it up in paint. Everybody so far is guessing at what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have better luck if you break your problem down into smaller steps. Step one is creating a function that draws a single "ring" of smaller circles. You already have that step done, all you need to do is separate it into its own function:

```
void drawCircle(int outerRadius, int innerRadius) {

  int numpoints = 10;
  float angleinc = 2 * PI / numpoints;
  for (int i = 0; i < numpoints; i++) {
    float x = cos(angleinc * i) * outerRadius;
    float y = sin(angleinc * i) * outerRadius;

    ellipse(x, y, innerRadius, innerRadius);
  }
}
```

Then, to draw a set of rings of increasing size, you simply call the function multiple times:

```
  drawCircle(50, 8);
  drawCircle(75, 12);
  drawCircle(100, 16);
```

Which you can condense into a `for loop`:

```
  for(int i = 2; i <= 4; i++){
    drawCircle(25*i, 4*i);
  }
```

The whole thing would look something like this:

```
void setup() {
  size (400, 400);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  noStroke();
  fill(0);
  smooth();
  translate(width/2, height/2);

  for(int i = 2; i <= 4; i++){
    drawCircle(25*i, 4*i);
  }
}

void drawCircle(int outerRadius, int innerRadius) {

  int numpoints = 10;
  float angleinc = 2 * PI / numpoints;
  for (int i = 0; i < numpoints; i++) {
    float x = cos(angleinc * i) * outerRadius;
    float y = sin(angleinc * i) * outerRadius;

    ellipse(x, y, innerRadius, innerRadius);
  }
}
```

This is just an example, and you'll have to play around with the numbers to make it look exactly like what you want, but the process is the same: break your problem down into smaller steps, isolate those steps into functions that do one thing, and then call those functions to accomplish your overall goal.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i got your question right-
The formula of a circle around the origin is x=R*cos(angle) y=R*sin(angle) where angel is going between 0 to 2*pi

if you want to draw the circle around point lets say around (x',y'), the formula will be x= x' + R*cos(angle)  y= y' + r*sin(angle)

The code:

```
  float epsilon = 0.0001f;
    float R = 5.5.f; 
    for (float angle = 0.0; angle < 2*PI; angle += epsilon ) {
        float x = x' + R*cos(angle);
        float y = y' + R*sin(angle);
        drawPoint(x,y);
        if( /*condition for changing the radius*/ )
        {
            R = R*2; // or any change you want to do for R
        }
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't really make any sense to me aviyaChe, I am very new to processing. Plus, my processing program said the x' and y' things are incorrect. All I wanna do is create another set of points inside the original set, so like the original circle of points, I wish to add another circle of points inside smaller than before - in the cleanest way possible, without creating numerous nested loops.

Comment: This is a pseudo code, you need to declare x' and y'. The question is not clear, can you add an image or something?

Comment: x' and y' were missing from the above equations. This was the missing piece I needed to get my formulas to work.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably easiest if you use *two* for loops: one for loop to draw the circle at a certain radius and another for loop which has the previous for loop in it which increases the radius.

```
int numCircles = 3;

//This for loop increases the radius and draws the circle with another for loop
for (int j = 0; j < numCircles; j++)
{
  //This for loop draws the actual circle
  for (int i = 0; i < numpoints; i++)
  {
    float x = cos(angleinc * i) * radius;
    float y = sin(angleinc * i) * radius;

    ellipse(x, y, 4, 4);
  }
  //(add code here that increases the radius)
}
```